# OpenLayers text label fuzzy

Tags: text, label, openlayers, openlayers-6

I have an issue with OpenLayers (v 6.14.1 from npm) where the text on the text label is rather fuzzy.

See the attached image. Compare the text labels with the text in the dialog to the right.

[image: map showing text labels]

I create the map with `pixelRatio: 1`, but that shouldn't affect this (?)

```
  const map = new Map({
    target: div,
    view: new View({
      center: fromLonLat ([startLocation.lon, startLocation.lat]),
      zoom: startLocation.zoom,
      constrainResolution: true,
    }),
    pixelRatio: 1, //Important, otherwise tiles (WMS) with strange size will be requested
  });
```

I create the text label thus:

```
export default function (feature, resolution, options) {
  return new Text ({
          font: 'Normal 14px serif', // Normal 14px Arial
          text: getText (feature, resolution, options),
          fill: new Fill ({ color: 'black' }),
          stroke: new Stroke ({ color: 'white', width: 2 }),
          offsetX: -12,
          offsetY: -8,
          textAlign: 'right',
          textBaseline: 'bottom',
          placement: 'point',
  });
}
```

I've already tried other fonts (e.g. a sans-serif).

Comment: You can ensure standard size WMS tiles by setting `hidpi: false` in the TileWMS options without affecting pixelRatio for other layers.

Comment: Thanks for that @Mike; I did as you suggested, and removed `pixelRatio: 1` from the `new Map ...`. I'd say the text is quite a bit sharper. Make your comment an answer so I can accept it etc?

Answer (score 1):

I did as @Mike suggested - see their comment under the question - here's the result:
[image]

I think the labels are now a fair bit sharper. Picture doesn't show this too well tho'.